# Why is De Moivre's theorem not generalised for $(\sin x+i\cos x)$?

Tags: trigonometry, complex-numbers

A representation of the form $(\sin x+i\cos x)^n$ can be reduced as follows

$$( \sin x + i \cos x )^n$$

$$( \cos (90-x) + i \sin(90-x) )^n$$

$$( \cos (90n - nx) + i \sin(90n - nx) )$$

Now for all odd values of $n$:

$$( \cos (90n - nx) + i \sin(90n - nx) ) = (\sin nx + i \cos nx)$$

So basically can we generalize this as follows?

For all odd and rational values of $n$

$$( \sin x + i \cos x )^n =(\sin nx + i \cos nx)$$

Comment: Are you sure that $\cos (90n - nx) = \sin nx$ for *all* odd n?

Comment: I am asking that exact question , what is the catch or blunder i overlooked ?

Comment: $\cos(180^\circ+x)=-\cos(x)$ and $\sin(180^\circ +x)=-\sin x$, so the identity holds for all $n\equiv 1\pmod4$. However, it would not be a *generalisation* of De Moivre's formula, because it is clearly a weaker result (for instance, it tells nothing of the even case). At most, it would be a *consequence*.

Answer (score 1):

First, $\cos(90n-nx)=\cos(90n)\cos(nx)+\sin(90n)\sin(nx)$. Now, for odd values on $n$ we have $\cos(90n)=0,\sin(90n)=(-1)^{\lfloor \frac{n-1}{2}\rfloor}$, thus $$\cos(90n-nx)=(-1)^{\lfloor \frac{n-1}{2}\rfloor}\sin(nx)$$ and you can split to the cases $n=1\pmod 4$ and $n=3\pmod 4$ (any you can look for the case where $n$ is even).

Second, we can write the following - by de moivre we have $$(\cos x-i\sin x)^n=\cos(nx)-i\sin(nx)\tag{1}$$ Now $$\sin x+i\cos x=i(\cos x-i\sin x)\tag{2}$$
And eventually,

> $$\forall n\in\mathbb{N}:\ (\sin x+i\cos x)^n=\left[i(\cos x-i\sin x)\right]^n=i^n(\cos(nx)-i\sin(nx))$$